# Property of $(\chi(g))_{g\in G, \chi\in \hat{G}}$ for a finite abelian group $G$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-groups, characters

Let $k$ be a field, $G$ be a finite abelian group such that $\operatorname{ch}=0$ or $\operatorname{ch}(k)\nmid \#G$.

Then, the dual group $\hat{G}$ is defined by

> $\hat{G}=\{\chi\mid {\rm group~homomorphism}~ \chi:G\to k^{*}\}$.

Consider $\#G$-dimensional $k$-vector space $k^G=\oplus_{g\in G}k$ and
$k$-linear map $\phi: k^G\to k^{\hat{G}}$ s

> $\phi((a_g)_{g\in G})=(\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g)a_g)_{\chi\in \hat{G}}$

I want to know the property of $\phi$ such as determinant, trace, inverse map...

Does this map have a name? If you know of any good books or papers, please let me know.

Comment: Have you ordered the elements of $G$ so that a matrix would make sense?

Comment: No. $G$ don't have order.   So My wording is not exactly correct. I have corrected my post.

Comment: Your notation makes it look like $\chi$ varies.  That's not the case, right?

Comment: I am very sorry. We made a serious typographical error. It has been corrected.

Comment: Thanks for correction, but I think there's now a typo: $\hat{G}a$ makes no sense, I think this $a$ should be deleted.

Comment: In the case of a cyclic group isn't this just the finite Fourier transform? Which will then extend via the  structure theorem for finite abelian groups.

Comment: This still doesn't make sense (at least to me).

Comment: @Randall I think it does, the sequence $(a_g)_{g\in G}$ gets mapped by $\phi$ to the sequence $(b_\chi)_{\chi\in\hat{G}}$, where $b_\chi:=\sum_{x\in G}\chi(x)a_x$. I think that it's more usual to write these sequences as sums in the group algebra(s).

Comment: Perhaps see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform_on_finite_groups ??

Comment: I apologize for the repeated misprints. I Corrected.